# How to wait some seconds only for a user discord bot python

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Ok I am making a currency bot in python. I am pretty fluent in python (Just haven't used coroutine that much)

What I want to achieve is that bot doesn't respond to a user if the user has sent a message in the previous 20 seconds. time.sleep won't work here since it blocks all code (Other user should be getting replied). I just can't figure out how to do it.

```
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author==client.user:
        return
    await make_bank(message.author.id)
    if message.content=="A":
        await message.channel.send("Done! Wait 20 secs.")
```

Comment: Please add your code, also instead of `time.sleep` you can use `asyncio.sleep`

Comment: I had that in my code. Lemme add it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `wait_for` function with a timeout kwarg

```py
if message.content == "A":
    await message.channel.send("Done! Wait 20 secs.")

    def check(m):
        return m.author == message.author

    try:
        await client.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=20.0)
        # Code here will be executed if the user sends a message within those 20 seconds
        await message.channel.send("Uh oh, you were supposed to wait for 20 seconds")
    except asyncio.TimeoutError:
        # User didn't send a message in 20 seconds
        await message.channel.send("Thanks for waiting!")
```

#### Reference:

- [`Client.wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for)

Comment: It keeps on sending "Uh oh, you were supposed to wait for 20 seconds"

Comment: I tried the code and it works flawlessly. you’re doing something wrong

Comment: I was reading about it yesterday and did some changes but now there is 1 problem. It doesn't respond to first message and waits 20 secs then responds

Comment: I don't quite understand what's the problem here

Comment: I basically wanna make a leveling system like mee6(XP is added every minute if a user messages) How can I achieve this?